# Draw segmented circle on Google map v2

Tags: android

I know how to draw a a circle on map v2 using circle options. However I was wondering, is there a way I can segment the circle (sort of like into Arcs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It can not be done using CircleOptions. I will have to create custom view and add it on the map